# Is Ruby on Rails slow with medium traffic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I made some searches on Google, and I read some posts, articles and benchmarks about Ruby on Rails being slow and I am planning to build one website that will have a good amount of users inserting data and there will be some applications to process this data (maybe in Ruby, you can help me choosing the language).

What is the real performance of Ruby on Rails with large traffic ?
Thank you !

Comment: You'll get better answers if you enter each of the questions you have listed here in as a separate SO question.

Comment: The answer to the first two questions is *it depends*.

Comment: What do you think is "good amount of users"? Also, don't worry so much about the scalability until you get some traction. Focus on making the user experience the best possible.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking a lot of questions, so I'll just try to answer you're first one. It is true that ruby, as a language, is slower compared to some others. This means that rails may not perform as well as some other frameworks. However, most websites will not receive the sort of traffic that poses a problem. The productivity gained by using rails most definitely outweighs the potential performance issues you may have later.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic web pages are slower than static, in general. Scale and performance are more about good design and caching than language choice.